# Linter for json schema directory

Tags: json, jsonschema, lint

My team build an API where for all the inputs and outputs use JSON Schema to validate the data, the project is growing and yesterday I detect that we already have 85 JSON files and on each file a JSON schema to validate something, I also detect that I have so many refactors to do on each file, for example, a lot of duplicate code that should be extracted and put it as a single schema and reference this schema on each file. So I tried to google it a library to scan this directory and help me to detect this kind of errors and also a JSON schema linter that helps me to detect other errors, but I couldn't find anything. So I'm posting this question to know if someone is having the same problem and found some tool that resolves it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used this library before, but here's an example of what you could do. The library itself is not the important part here.

Download http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema and save it as `draft04-metaschema.json` (or whatever meta-schema you're using for your schemas). Use [ajv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-cli) from npm:

```
npm install -g ajv-cli
ajv validate -s draft04-metaschema.json -d your-schema.json
```

This would validate your schema against the metaschema specified to ensure that it's valid. You could use this same methodology to validate your schemas using any other library you wish. Hopefully that's enough to get you started though.

Answer (score 2):

I also had to find a way to validate schemas. `ajv validate -s draft06-metaschema.json -d your-schema.json` checks only for basic things (e.g., it doesn't check `$ref` values and regexes). `ajv compile -s your-schema.json` checks for many more things and prints error messages (like `error: Invalid regular expression: /^(\d|[12]\d|3[01]$/: Unterminated group`).

So I use the following script (`validate_schema.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

[ $# = 3 ]
url_draft=$1
json_draft=$2
json_target=$3

jq -e '.["$schema"]=="'"$url_draft"'"' "$json_target"

# False positives are possible though:
ajv validate -s "$json_draft" -d "$json_target"

ajv compile -s "$json_target"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the project i'm working on now we are using [tv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4) to validate JSON Schema files, not 'linting' per se but should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I read the tv4 docs but is a library to validate data against a JSON schema not to validate the JSON schema file perse

Comment: You would validate your schemas against the metaschema defined by the `$schema` property in your schemas. Some other libraries include this directly in their API so that you can validate a schema, but underneath that's all they're doing.

Answer (score -1):

There is a JSON schema linter available at https://www.json-schema-linter.com/ which also has a **WebAPI**. It catches some common errors in JSON schema files.